# Can I get the classic "run command" window

Tags: unity-dash, command-line

I love unity but I hate it when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> brings up the dash. Is it possible to just remap <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> so that the thing looks like exactly the old <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>

[image]

I know what I want is like going back in time but I really loved that fast command runner in old gnome. I can bring up terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run anything I want but it sometimes is a overkill to bring up something like that for small things.

And I used to like the fact that older window was fast, had autofill and would disappear after launching the command. Or is there a utilty that looks somewhat like that and can be installed and mapped to some key.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This answer is not exactly to get the classic <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> Run command windows.

But we can achieve something simillar to good old "Run command" window using the below programs

> - Compizconfig Settings Manager
> - gmrun

If you dont have these packages installed. Here is the steps:

Open **terminal** and type

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install gmrun
```

Now open Compizconfig-setting-manager using dash. Navigate to

- **General** -> **Commands** (Enable commands)
  [image]
- Open **Commands** tab -> In **Command line 0** enter the value **gmrun**
  [image]
- Open **Key Bindings** tab -> In **Run Command 0** 
  [image]

  - Click on **Disabled** icon and make it Enabled(tick mark)
  - Click **Grab key combination** and use your desired key(I choose <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
    [image]
- Done now you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to open the "Run Applications" box
  [image]

Comment: Awesome. Finally found a replacement

Answer (score 0):

An easy but not exactly equivalent way:
`Sytem Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts`.